# Breaking out section of US States with tmap and simple features

Tags: r, r-sf, tmap

I am trying to make a map with US States broken out from the rest of the country using tmap and simple features. I am nudging the coordinates the desired amount (in the below example its the eastern region) - but for some reason Florida and New York are refusing to move. I tried manually adjusting outside the loop with the same results. If I want to move a sf object by a constant what is the best way of approaching it?

Also - why is Michigan looking like it melted in lake Michigan?

```
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(tigris)

us_geo <- states(class = "sf")

us_geo$PADD[us_geo$NAME %in% 
              c("Maine", "Vermont", "New Hampshire", "Massachusetts", "Connecticut", "Rhode Island",
                "New York", "Pennsylvania", "New Jersey", "Delaware", "District of Columbia", "Maryland",
                "West Virginia", "Virginia", "North Carolina", "South Carolina", "Georgia", "Florida")] <- "East Coast"

us_geo$PADD[us_geo$NAME %in% 
              c("South Dakota", "North Dakota","Nebraska", "Kansas", "Oklahoma", 
                "Minnesota", "Iowa", "Missouri", "Wisconsin", "Illinois", "Indiana",
                "Michigan", "Ohio", "Kentucky", "Tennessee")] <- "Midwest"

us_geo$PADD[us_geo$NAME %in% 
              c("New Mexico", "Texas", "Arkansas", "Louisiana", "Alabama", "Mississippi")] <- "Gulf Coast"

us_geo$PADD[us_geo$NAME %in% 
              c("Montana", "Idaho", "Wyoming", "Utah", "Colorado")] <- "Rocky Mountain"

us_geo$PADD[us_geo$NAME %in% 
              c("Washington", "Oregon", "Nevada", "Arizona", "California")] <- "West Coast"

us_geo <- us_geo[!is.na(us_geo$PADD),]



x <- grep("East", us_geo$PADD)

for(i in x){
  us_geo[i,]$geometry[[1]][[1]][[1]][,1] <- us_geo[i,]$geometry[[1]][[1]][[1]][,1] +5
}

qtm(us_geo)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually not moving all the objects in the MULTIPOLYGON. I guess the word with multi- in front confused me. Just needed to add another loop. Also, I changed the resolution to make Michigan reappear.

```
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(tigris)

us_geo <- states(class = "sf", res = "5m", cb = TRUE)

us_geo$PADD[us_geo$NAME %in% 
              c("Maine", "Vermont", "New Hampshire", "Massachusetts", "Connecticut", "Rhode Island",
                "New York", "Pennsylvania", "New Jersey", "Delaware", "District of Columbia", "Maryland",
                "West Virginia", "Virginia", "North Carolina", "South Carolina", "Georgia", "Florida")] <- "East Coast"

us_geo$PADD[us_geo$NAME %in% 
              c("South Dakota", "North Dakota","Nebraska", "Kansas", "Oklahoma", 
                "Minnesota", "Iowa", "Missouri", "Wisconsin", "Illinois", "Indiana",
                "Michigan", "Ohio", "Kentucky", "Tennessee")] <- "Midwest"

us_geo$PADD[us_geo$NAME %in% 
              c("New Mexico", "Texas", "Arkansas", "Louisiana", "Alabama", "Mississippi")] <- "Gulf Coast"

us_geo$PADD[us_geo$NAME %in% 
              c("Montana", "Idaho", "Wyoming", "Utah", "Colorado")] <- "Rocky Mountain"

us_geo$PADD[us_geo$NAME %in% 
              c("Washington", "Oregon", "Nevada", "Arizona", "California")] <- "West Coast"

us_geo <- us_geo[!is.na(us_geo$PADD),]

qtm(us_geo)

x <- grep("East", us_geo$PADD)

for(i in x){
  for(j in 1:length(us_geo[i,]$geometry[[1]])){
  us_geo[i,]$geometry[[1]][[j]][[1]][,1] <- us_geo[i,]$geometry[[1]][[j]][[1]][,1] +5
  }
}

qtm(us_geo)
```

[image]